# Move checkout progress to top

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, onepage-checkout

In the internet are described different ways to diplay checkout progress in the left sidebar. But how to diplay it in the top of the page?

And I have a second question: how to know at what step the user is? I need to set a CSS class to a element in dependence of what step the user is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with CSS only. You can find the css below. It basically comes down to moving the `.col-left` above `.col-main` using the `2columns-left` layout for example. When making both columns 100% width this will force one under the other.

Determining in what step the user is can best be done by extending the javascript `Checkout` class found in file `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js`. THere is a method called `gotoSection` that is called to move the user to the next step

```
#checkout-step-login h3 { margin-bottom: 5px; }
#checkout-step-login .col2-set .col-1 { float: right; }
#checkout-step-login .col2-set .col-2 { float: left; }

#checkout-step-login .col-1 ul { list-style: disc; padding-left: 17px; margin: 13px 0 0 0; }
#checkout-step-login ul.form-list { list-style: none; padding-left: 0; margin: 20px 0 0 0; }
#checkout-step-login #remember-me-box .link-tip { display: none; }

#opc-shipping .step-title { display: none; }
.step-title .number { display: none; }


#checkoutSteps { position: relative; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; }

#checkoutSteps .step-title { width: 20%; height: 20px; position: absolute; top: 0; padding: 9px 0 5px 0; }
#checkoutSteps .step-title h2 { width: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; }
#opc-login .step-title { left: 0; }
#opc-billing .step-title { left: 20%; }
#opc-shipping_method .step-title { left: 40%; }
#opc-payment .step-title { left: 60%; }
#opc-review .step-title { left: 80%; }

#checkoutSteps .step { margin-top: 34px; }

#checkoutSteps .section { border-bottom: none; }

.opc .allow .step-title, .opc .active .step-title { background-color: #A4A4A4; }
```

Comment: Sadly the Github link doesn't work anymore...

Comment: oh crap, did a cleanup. I'll add template and css to answer tonight (in about 3 hours)

Comment: @loeffel took me some digging through old external hard drives but this should be it (see above). it's all CSS. If you run into any issues just scream

Comment: Thanks for this, but it's the js part that is giving me a headache right now... :D

Comment: hmz, I suck at JS but if you have any errors let me know. Actually, just send me a mail or something. this might not be the best place to go into a lengthy discussion